# Chrome not displaying after being closed

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11

I have this weird issue that if I close chrome (clicking x on last tab or last window) then I can't open it again. I can see that it has running processes and everything and if I kill them all Chrome will be able to open up again. I've tried:

- Adding administrator access
- Restart system
- Reinstall chrome
- Added compatibility mode for window 8

Newest Chrome and Windows 11 pro fully updated.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experiences and found two reasons.

1. The browser has actually crashed because of a bad add-on or malware.  I find Zemana excellent at finding browser malware.  It is free and I am not associated with it.
2. The new window has opened off-screen.  To pull it back -

   a. As soon as you have clicked the icon, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.  This pops down the system menu.

   b. Type in <kbd>M</kbd> for Move (even though you cant see it).

   c. Press any arrow key (at least once).  Now you can either drag it with the mouse or just use arrow keys to move it into view.